# Using regex in flask restful api route url

Tags: python, regex, rest, flask

I am trying to add regex based url for flask api. but it doesn't seems to work. and i am unable to find a solution on documentation too.

```
scheduler_blueprint = Blueprint('scheduling_api', __name__)
api = TalentApi()
api.init_app(scheduler_blueprint)
api.route = types.MethodType(api_route, api)

@api.route('/tasks/<string:id>')
class TaskById(Resource):
....

@api.route('/tasks/resume/')
class ResumeTasks(Resource):
....
```

where string:id should be a hash other than 'resume'
as far as i know, regex is the only thing which i can use in this scenario to remove this conflict.
how can i use regex in url ***for flask restful api*** ?

Comment: A regex for a 32 or more digit sequence is `\d{32,}` or `[0-9]{32,}` - no idea how it can help here.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I would just use `<int:task_id>` instead. It will enforce an integer. If you really want to go down the regex way, you might take a look at [*this*](http://code.runnable.com/UiUoCDy0NHNrAAA_/how-to-use-regular-expressions-for-routing-with-flask-for-python-and-regex) and use @stribizhev 's regex.

Comment: @HamZa: the task_id is in hash (i am using apscheduler and its a job id which is in hash format => string)

Comment: @SaadAbdullah Then I think you need to re-edit your question since it's quite confusing. Apparently you don't want 32 digits but a 32 hexadecimal string. Which means the regex will be `[a-f0-9]{32}`

Comment: but how its confusing?

Answer (score 4):

Write a [custom url converter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#custom-converters) that recognizes 32 hex characters. Register the converter with the app and use it in the route.

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class TaskIDConverter(BaseConverter):
    regex = r'[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}'

# register the converter when creating the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['task_id'] = TaskIDConverter

# use the converter in the route
@app.route('/user/<task_id:id>')
def process_user(id):
    ...

# will recognize /user/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
# will 404 on /user/123, /user/123abc456, etc.
```

If the id is really an int, and not a string that happens to have only digits, use the following converter instead. It converts the value to an int, and makes sure that the value doesn't start with 0, which would result in fewer than 32 digits in the int.

```
class TaskIDConverter(BaseConverter):
    regex = r'[1-9]\d{31,}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return str(value)
```